# How to save image from url on device private folder on Android app

Tags: android, image, android-volley

I am new to this image using applications so I will try to be as explicit as can. What I want to do is download images dinamically using urls and save them on a private folder inside the app, so if the app is uninstalled the images will be deleted. I want the images to be linked to an object based on some parameter say object.image = imageName something like that. I am asking for guidance on what to look for or tutorials, I have used volley for download images but do not know quite how to save them and use them from private folder. Any help or suggestions would be great, thanks

Comment: Refer this guide on Saving photos: https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics#TaskPath         It describes how you can save photos in a directory that is accessible only to app.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will look into it